# There is no application properties in Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a logging library that included in Spring Application. There is an initialisation:

```
package my.project.logger;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;

public class MyLibClass implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();

        final Binder binder = Binder.get(environment);

        String log = binder.bind("logger.log", Bindable.of(String.class))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Mandatory log name is not specified."));
    }
}
```

It works fine with just `spring-boot-starter-web` but fails with there is no such property when `spring-cloud-gcp-starter` plugged in.

Could you please advise what can be wrong here and why Environment doesn't contain application.properties in case of spring-cloud-gcp-starter ?

Comment: Did you check the following: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config.html

Comment: have you tried with `@Configuration` above the `MyLibClass`.. ?

Comment: @DannyFried, yes, that's exactly what i'm looking for! Thanks a lot!